# How to find DOM element id/value by its offset

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i want to find DOM element id/value by its offset. may be the picture explain exactly. i have a div that appoint ranges of value. and buttons that change values but ranges div is fix. now i want to find the ranges value after buttons event.

[image]

```
this my html code. 

 <div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="Slider" id="slider">
   <li class="year ruler" ng-attr-id="{{y.year}}" ng-repeat="y in years"    style="top: {{y.top}}px">{{y.year}}<label class="index"> -</label></li>
 <div id="ranges" class="ranges"></div>
<div class="panel">
    <button ng-click="up()">up</button>
    <button ng-click="down()">down</button><br>
    <button ng-click="zoomOut()">+</button>
    <button ng-click="zoomIn()">-</button>
</div>
```

i use this code to find value but alert undefined

```
var dom= $(document.body).find('[offsetTop = '+80+']');
    alert($(dom).attr('id'));
```

Comment: `offsetTop` isn't a HTML attribute, but a property of the Object `Element`. So you can't select them this way. You'll need to traverse all elements you need to select and find out if their offsetTop is within your specification.

Comment: Not sure I get this, do you want to get an element at a specific position, if so `document.elementFromPoint(80, 0)`

Comment: @adeneo, I think the OP wants to select all elements within a certain range. `document.elementFromPoint` isn't designed to do that. (He's making a time line, and wants to select all events within that bit of history is my guess as a history teacher).

Comment: @Mouser, exactly i want to create a time line.

Comment: @Hadi, XGreen's answer provides a general jQuery way to do this (plain JS code can be just as short as that example though). The events you want to select, which type of element are they and are they contained by a containing element other than `body`?

Comment: @Mouser my type of event element is  <li class="year ruler" ng-attr-id="{{y.year}}" ng-repeat="y in years"    style="top: {{y.top}}px">{{y.year}}<label class="index"> -</label></li>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the jQuery's filter function to filter elements based on their offset

```
function getElementByTopOffset(selector, offset){
    return $(selector).filter(function( index, elem) {
       return $(elem).offset().top == offset;
    });
}
```

Also if you fancy doing in completely vanilla here could be a solution:

```
function getElementByTopOffset(selector, offset){
    return [].filter.call(document.querySelectorAll(selector), function(elem) {
          return elem.offsetTop == offset
    });
}
```